# I'm getting 0, however, I know that there are some new customers

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

Please help me - I'm trying to get only new customers of each month.
Here's my logic: emails of this month with a where not exists in all records before the month.

```
SELECT COUNT(email)
FROM `bc_order_billing_addresses`
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT email
                  FROM `bc_order_billing_addresses`
                  LEFT JOIN `bc_order` ON `.bc_order`.order_id = `bc_order_billing_addresses`.order_id
                  WHERE order_created_date_time < '2022-10-01T00:00:00');
```

I'm getting 0, however, I know that there are some new customers. (edited)

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results, as tabular text. It is unclear what the structure of your tables look like.

Comment: `inner join` maybe? but show tables.

Comment: Seems you are mixing `WHERE NOT EXISTS` and `WHERE email NOT IN`

Comment: The NOT EXISTS subquery needs to be correlated, i.e. include a condition referencing the outer query table.

Answer (score 0):

I tried HoneyBadger's suggestion in the comments. It works!

```
SELECT DISTINCT count(email)
FROM `my-project-24hr-339515.data_24hr.bc_order_billing_addresses`
WHERE email NOT IN (
  SELECT email
  FROM `my-project-24hr-339515.data_24hr.bc_order_billing_addresses`
  left join `my-project-24hr-339515.data_24hr.bc_order`
  On `my-project-24hr-339515.data_24hr.bc_order`.order_id = `my-project-24hr-339515.data_24hr.bc_order_billing_addresses`.order_id
  where order_created_date_time < '2022-10-01T00:00:00'
);
```

Comment: Glad you found a solution that works for you, why the `DISTINCT` though? There can only be one count